# Specific content by country in multiple languages

Tags: multi-language, plugin-wpml

In a project we need to have country specific FAQ-content for each country. As a twist the FAQ-content for each country has to be translated to the main language of the country and at least english, sometimes even more languages.

For example the FAQ with relevant content for the swedish market will be available in swedish by default and english as translation. The FAQ-content for the spanish market will be available in spanish, english and catalan.

In my mind I think of accessing content like something like this:

```
# Swedish FAQ
example.com/faq/se/      - defaults to swedish
example.com/faq/se/sv    - explicitly requesting swedish
example.com/faq/se/en    - explicitly requesting english

# Spanish FAQ
example.com/faq/es/      - defaults to spanish
example.com/faq/es/ca    - explicitly requesting catalan
example.com/faq/es/en    - explicitly requesting english
```

Is it possible to achieve this with [WPML](https://wpml.org/)? If not any bright ideas how to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to make it multisite and then use WPML on each subsite. So it'll look like:

```
se.example.com/
se.example.com/en
se.example.com/sv

es.example.com/
es.example.com/en
es.example.com/sv
```